# MS SQL как сравнить строки, если одна получена через FETCH INTO

Tags: строки, sql-server

Столкнулся с глупой проблемой, когда писал процедуру в MS SQL, а именно, в этом фрагменте кода:

```
FETCH NEXT from cursor INTO @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--@comp_name и @name объявлены как nvarchar(255)
if (@comp_name <> @name)
begin
    --тут делаю важные вещи
    @comp_name = @name
    FETCH NEXT from cursor INTO @name
end
END
```

Даже если строки разные, процедура никогда не заходит в тело условника. Пробовал выводить обе переменные, на выводе они разные. Но видимо Fetch как-то портит [[[[[[@name](/users/861/namespace)](/users/861/namespace)](/users/861/namespace)](/users/861/namespace)](/users/861/namespace)](/users/861/namespace). Без Fetch подобное сравнение работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Глупейшая ошибка, просто не присвоил никакого значения @comp_name.
Сказывается то, что почти не работал с ms sql.